# ERROR: Can't change MAC: interface up or not permission: Invalid argument

Tags: 13.04

So, I was messing around with aircrack & macchanger and following some tutorials. I typed the following command into the terminal

```
macchanger --mac 00:11:22:33:44:55 wlan0
```

and I got the following error

```
ERROR: Can't change MAC: interface up or not permission: Invalid argument
```

I have no clue what this means, so i done some digging through google and come across one article **[here](https://perot.me/mac-spoofing-what-why-how-and-something-about-coffee)** and if you go the the third comment from the bottom, someone else has run into the same problem, and there was a reply in the second comment from the bottom that simply stated.

> As you have guessed, this means that the Linux driver for your device doesn't allow changing the MAC address (whereas the Windows one does). Unfortunately, there's not much you can do about it, other than patching the driver yourself or bugging Realtek about it.

Ok, well why is that so? that's pretty stupid, is there any way to get around this, or what drivers am I supposed to be looking at replacing?

How do we go about **"patching the driver"**?

Answer (score 0):

you should have to do that with sudo , unless you are a root user you cant do that.

```
sudo macchanger --mac 00:11:22:33:44:55 wlan0
```

will help you.

Comment: I used sudo su before I entered the command

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turn down your network interface?

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
macchanger --mac 00:11:22:33:44:55 wlan0
ifconfig wlan0 up
```